# Using screen, commands like less and man don't clear the screen afterwards

Tags: gnu-screen

In contrast to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/106637/less-command-clearing-screen-upon-exit-how-to-switch-it-off) I want the clearing of the screen re-enabled for `less`. It works fine in my `xterm` terminal under Cygwin/mintty or Gnome Terminal (both `xterm`s).

*However*, when inside a [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session, the clearing of the screen is somehow disabled. I tried several things, like

```
screen -T xterm
```

or putting the [autonuke](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Autonuke) statement in my `~/.screenrc`. Also, inside the screen session

```
export TERM=xterm
tset
```

has no effect. So, now I'm out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

Comment: hmm, i'm seeing the same thing, on Cygwin/mintty, Debian/putty, Ubuntu/putty.  in putty i use *putty* as the TERM instead of *xterm* but that's the only real difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably want to avoid `screen -T` or resetting TERM away from its default value while inside *screen* sessions (it should probably be `screen` or at least something that starts with `screen`).

Try putting the following line in your `.screenrc`:

```
altscreen on
```

To activate it on a per-session basis, you can do <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>:altscreen on<kbd>Return</kbd>.

My manpage says:

> altscreen on|off
>
> If  set  to on, "alternate screen" support is enabled in virtual termi-
>           nals, just like in xterm.  Initial setting is `off'.

BTW, I have explained the [root cause of the “screen clearing” (actually alternate/normal screen swapping)](https://superuser.com/questions/136162/how-can-i-still-see-the-man-text-after-i-quit-man/136205#136205) in another answer.
It is possible that your `screen` terminfo entry is missing `smcup`/`rmcup` or that your *screen* does not support alternate screens. Both of those seem less likely that `altscreen` being off.

Comment: I'm using Mac and I don't have an altscreen command. Any other way of doing this?

Comment: @Dana: What version of *screen* (`screen --version`)? It seems that `altscreen` has been around since *screen* 3.9.13. Based on [opensource.apple.com](http://www.opensource.apple.com/), it seems like the Apple-bundled version of *screen* has been newer than 3.9.13 since 10.3. Just as a reminder, it is not a regular “shell command”, but a command that is specific to *screen*; it must be entered at the *screen* “colon prompt” (Control+a, then `:altscreen on`, then Return).