# on quit, 'less' does NOT clear its contents when run in a 'screen' session

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, less

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using screen, commands like less and man don't clear the screen afterwards](https://superuser.com/questions/137714/using-screen-commands-like-less-and-man-dont-clear-the-screen-afterwards)

When I quit 'less' in a normal bash, it clears the previous contents displayed by 'less' and shows the bash contents again. This is the defualt behavior and what I desire.

However, when I use 'less' in a 'screen' session (still bash inside the screen session), after quitting it does not erase the contents shown by 'less' and the contents of bash are gone (still having a new bash comand line prompt though).

How can I make it so that less *does* clear its display after quitting, *even* though I am using it within a 'screen' session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this command to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
altscreen on
```

You can also do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> `: altscreen on` from within `screen` to toggle it on or off in the current session.

Make sure your `$LESS` environment variable does not contain `X` in its value.

Comment: Didn't work... uncommenting "altscreen on" did.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that these work:

```
$ tput smcup | od -c
$ tput rmcup | od -c
```

they should print something like:

```
0000000 033  [  ?  1  0  4  9  h
```

rather than:

```
0000000
```