# Getting the screen to delete contents of less, man, etc. after "q"

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using screen, commands like less and man don't clear the screen afterwards](https://superuser.com/questions/137714/using-screen-commands-like-less-and-man-dont-clear-the-screen-afterwards)

In bash without screen if I do a `less` or `man` and then type `q` to quit, the contents of the less or man page that was showing disappears and I'm left with my previous bash output plus a new prompt.  I like this.

With screen, when I enter "q" I'm left with whatever less/man/etc. page I was viewing plus a new prompt.  I don't like this.

Is there a screen option I can use?

screen 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06

GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: You know about the `clear` command right?

Comment: @Dunes, yes, but AFAIK **clear** will replace the contents of the window with blanks/background.  When I (q)uit less or man I want the contents to collapse to nothing as if the output of my less or man command was null.  That's what bash, without screen, does.

Comment: Whoa, after my question was migrated from stackoverflow to here I see in the margin that there are answers!  E.g., [link](http://superuser.com/questions/223898/on-quit-less-does-not-clear-its-contents-when-run-in-a-screen-session): the altscreen parameter is what I was looking for.