# Neither less or less -X clear screen on exit. (Trust me, I googled....)

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, tmux, less

Neither less or less -X clear screen on exit. At the same time, vim does....

Env iTerm2, protocol mosh, server Centos + tmux + zsh

iTerm2: report term as `xterm-256color`

tmux: `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'`, no change to alternate-screen

`$TERM` is final set to `screen-256color`

I also tried
    `tput smcup | od -c` and
    `tput rmcup | od -c`

suggested here [on quit, 'less' does NOT clear its contents when run in a 'screen' session](https://superuser.com/questions/223898/on-quit-less-does-not-clear-its-contents-when-run-in-a-screen-session). It outputs correct answer.