# GNU Screen garbling bmon

Tags: gnu-screen, ncurses

bmon runs fine in a regular terminal, however, when run from inside screen the output is garbled and unusable. This problem doesn't affect all curses applications - top and htop run fine. bwm-ng runs fine, but bwm-ng -o curses2 also results in garbed output.

The problem also occurs regardless of whether I set TERM to screen, screen-256color, or xterm. Additionally, the problem also occurs with tmux.

I'm at a loss... what settings am I missing to get screen to behave properly with bmon and the like?

---

*Additional information:*
The terminal is being accessed over SSH from an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. The remote machine is running Ubuntu 12.04, but the problem was also observed on a Ubuntu 10.10 server. screenrc was left empty for the test.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found here: [Using screen, commands like less and man don't clear the screen afterwards](https://superuser.com/questions/137714/using-screen-commands-like-less-and-man-dont-clear-the-screen-afterwards/137751#137751)

Put `altscreen on` in your `.screenrc` or just type

```
ctrl-a : altscreen on
```

Comment: I tried it in screen, but it didn't solve the problem. Is there something else I need to do?