# In screen, close emacs window AND scroll up

Tags: gnu-screen

When I use screen and I close an emacs window, the prompt remains at the bottom of the screen where than popping to where the prompt was before I opened emacs. How can I fix this? It only happens when I use screen. I don't like it, because it sometimes looks like I'm still in emacs, and I can't see my previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [Using screen, commands like less and man don't clear the screen afterwards](https://superuser.com/questions/137714/using-screen-commands-like-less-and-man-dont-clear-the-screen-afterwards/137751#137751)

Use GNU screens `altscreen on` either in your `.screenrc` file or just type

```
ctrl-a : altscreen on <return>
```

Here is another post that had your problem [gnu-screen-clearing-on-vim-less-etc-exit](https://serverfault.com/questions/270103/gnu-screen-clearing-on-vim-less-etc-exit).  They solved it as above.