# 'less' doesn't clear screen after quit

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, xterm, less

The default behavior for 'less' is to clear the screen after quitting. This behavior stopped when I started using:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Now 'less' leaves the last page I viewed on the screen, and I want to re-enable the default behavior of clearing the screen.

Googling this problem I found that people use the following command in their `~/.screenrc`:

```
altscreen on
```

I'm not sure if this is a mac-issue but I don't have this command available.

I'm using bash shell on Mac terminal and I have no `$LESS` environment variable defined.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The other question explicitly asks about the problem _inside_ GNU `screen`. This one has nothing to do with `screen`, as evidenced by, "I don't have [`altscreen`] available" and "I'm using bash shell on Mac terminal."

Comment: What happens when you call `less` like: `less -+F -+X <file>`? If that changes the behavior, your less is configured to behave that  way somewhere in you system configuration. If not, it's likely that your terminal doesn't support the alternate screen feature or doesn't have it enabled. You'd need the reverse of http://superuser.com/questions/136162/how-can-i-still-see-the-man-text-after-i-quit-man/136205#136205 or get a terminal that has the alternate screen feature.

Comment: @peth: This really isn't a duplicate question. As for your question, no matter how I play with the command line options, the last page always remains on the screen. I don't think this has something to do with the less configuration since this only started happening after I defined `export TERM=xterm`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your $LESS environment variable and make sure it doesn't specify -X. I specifically add this to $LESS, because I *don't* want the screen cleared. Here is a snipet from the manpage:

> -X or --no-init
>                 Disables sending the termcap  initialization  and  deinitialization
>                 strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deini-
>                 tialization string does something unnecessary,  like  clearing  the
>                 screen.

Comment: I have no $LESS environment variable defined at all

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this only started happening after I defined `export TERM=xterm`, so I believe this is not a problem of `less` definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Some clarification is needed: `less` will only **clear** the screen as a part of displaying a new page.  What is described in the question is the *alternate screen*, an xterm feature that `Terminal.app` supports.

When you see the screen cleared, that is because the terminal has switched to the *alternate screen* temporarily (to run `less`) and has switched back to the *normal screen* (showing just your shell prompt and whatever preceded that before running `less`).

`less` gets the information on how to switch to/from the alternate screen from the terminal description, using `$TERM` to find this information.  I don't see this in OSX *now* (the question dates from 2011), but some developers dislike the feature and remove it from the terminal description (for example, [FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/share/termcap/termcap?r1=200369&r2=200503)).

The question did not say what `$TERM` was before *changing* it to `xterm`.  That used a different terminal description, where the feature had not been removed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension to the answer by @KeithB.

check the options of LESS by `echo $LESS`. If it has option `-X`, remove it.

```
LESS="options"; export LESS
```

In options include options other than `-X`. More information, check the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less).